# Printing - Planning Calendar SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to print a planning calendar but I have a problem in CSS as interval time.

```
onPrint:function(){ 
  var $domTarget = this.byId("PC1").$()[0],
  sTargetContent = $domTarget.innerHTML,
  sOriginalContent = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = sTargetContent;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = sOriginalContent;
}
```

Print View:
[image]

Normal View:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Browsers remove certain CSS attributes by default when printing. The most common one is background settings but there might be others. There's a print setting to restore it.

If that doesn't work, have a look at the `@media=print` option that can add styles to prints specifically. I do not know if UI5 excludes certain things from their stylesheets for certain media. You could, for instance, replace the background settings with an image or something. This might force the right height/width and background colours.

I'm not saying this will solve your problems entirely, but compare these two images:

[image]

[image]

Edit: it might just work:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jorg, Thanks a lot for your answer, it works correctly when I use "Ctrl +P". In my case, I want to print just the planning calendar, not all of page, that why I have a function onPrint() above. Can you help me please?

Comment: You don’t know what kind of in line css you’re removing by replacing the entire dom or whatever impact that might have

Comment: There might be alternative approaches though